# Using ksdiff as THOR_MERGE tool in zshell

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zsh, merge-conflict-resolution, thor, kaleidoscope

I'm trying to run the [rails update script](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#the-update-task) with the following in my `.zshrc` file (for use in merge conflicts):

```
export THOR_MERGE="/usr/local/bin/ksdiff --merge --output $MERGED -- $LOCAL $REMOTE"
```

[Kaleidoscope](https://kaleidoscope.app/) opens up in merge mode however after conflict resolution no changes are persisted. I'm convinced that something must be wrong with the arguments or the order of it.

Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

It seems that `$MERGED` is not defined and [Kaleidoscope](https://kaleidoscope.app/) tries to write the generated file (the file which includes the conflict resolutions) in file `--` thus creating a new file. If only `$MERGED` was set as expected (the resolved file) this should work...

Answer (score 3):

I ended up creating a little wrapper script that I called `thor-merge-ksdiff` and set `THOR_MERGE=.../thor-merge-ksdiff` in my environment:

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

LOCAL=$2
REMOTE=$1
MERGED=$(mktemp)
if ksdiff --merge --output "$MERGED" -- "$LOCAL" --snapshot "$REMOTE" --snapshot; then
  mv $MERGED $LOCAL
fi
```

The `ksdiff` command line was taken from the latest Kaleidoscope 3 git integration.